# add second filter without removing the existing ones

Tags: sapui5

Hi i have a searchfield with this code behind it:

```
onSearch : function (oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getParameters().refreshButtonPressed) {
        // Search field's 'refresh' button has been pressed.
        // This is visible if you select any master list item.
        // In this case no new search is triggered, we only
        // refresh the list binding.
        this.onRefresh();
    } else {
        var andFilter = [];
        var sQuery = oEvent.getParameter("query");
        if (sQuery && sQuery.length > 0) {
            // add filters
            var oTableSearchState = [];
            oTableSearchState = [new Filter("Supplier", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery),                                        new Filter("BusArea", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery),             new Filter("CostCenter", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery),
            new Filter("FuncArea", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery)];
            andFilter.push(new Filter(oTableSearchState, false));
        }
        this._applySearch(andFilter);
   }
},
```

And a filter button that should add aditional filters. Something like this:

```
onSetFilter : function(oEvent) {
    var andFilter = [];
    andFilter.push(new Filter("BusArea", FilterOperator.EQ, "5000"));
    this._applySearch(andFilter);
},
```

But of course the "BusArea" part should be dependent on what filters are selected. It could be more than 1 filter. the _applySearch function looks like this:

```
_applySearch: function(andFilter) {
    var oViewModel = this.getModel("worklistView");
    this._oTable.getBinding("items").filter(andFilter, true);
    // changes the noDataText of the list in case there are no filter results
    if (andFilter.length !== 0) {
        oViewModel.setProperty("/tableNoDataText", 
        this.getResourceBundle().getText("worklistNoDataWithSearchText"));
    }
}
```

the problem is that when i add a filter via the filter button, the filters from the searchbar disappear and the other way arround. how can i change my code so that i can add the filters without removing the existing ones?

Comment: We applied multiple filters by maintaining a Filter array at Controller level. So, we would push filters to array first, like, this.aFilters.push(oFilter) and then apply this.aFilters to binding. Looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to get the Filters from the binding info and push back together with the new Filter using `and`.

```
this._oTable.getBindingInfo("items").filters.aFilters;
```

Comment: ok, i like that but this way the filters will stack. do you have any thoughts on how to solve that problem?

Comment: @freshrebel I see your point now. I may misunderstand what you want to achieve. Is it possible that every time the search button is hit, you loop the all Filters control and build the filters with values all over again?

Comment: ok but my filters(so not the searchfiel) are comming from a dialog like this: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ViewSettingsDialog/preview . can i get the values from the dialog even after it is closed?

Answer (score 1):

After our conversation on the chat, I have made this snippet using a global model.

https://jsbin.com/pewavuhonu/edit?html,output

The ComboBox and the Button simulates your Dialog.
The input simulates the SearchField

Both are binded against the global "filtersModel", and both call the _calculateFilters() function when submiting the info

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>MVC with XmlView</title>

  <!-- Load UI5, select "blue crystal" theme and the "sap.m" control library -->
  <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
   src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
   data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
   data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'
   data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax='complex'></script>


  <!-- DEFINE RE-USE COMPONENTS - NORMALLY DONE IN SEPARATE FILES -->

  <!-- define a new (simple) View type as an XmlView
   - using data binding for the Button text
   - binding a controller method to the Button's "press" event
   - also mixing in some plain HTML
   note: typically this would be a standalone file -->

  <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="my.own.controller">
   <Panel headerText="Filters">
    <VBox>
     <HBox>
      <Label text="Filter by Customer:" class="sapUiSmallMarginTop sapUiSmallMarginEnd"/>
      <ComboBox id="comboBox" selectedKey="{filtersModel>/customerFilter}">
       <items>
        <core:Item key="VINET" text="VINET" />
        <core:Item key="TOMSP" text="TOMSP" />
        <core:Item key="HANAR" text="HANAR" />
        <core:Item key="VICTE" text="VICTE" />
        <core:Item key="SUPRD" text="SUPRD" />
       </items>
      </ComboBox>
      <Button text="Apply this Filter" press="_calculateFilters"></Button>
     </HBox>
    </VBox>
    <VBox>
     <HBox>
      <Input value="{filtersModel>/shipAddressFilter}" id="input" submit="_calculateFilters" width="500px" placeholder="Filter by ShipAddress: Write and enter for filtering"/>
     </HBox>
    </VBox>
   </Panel>
   <Panel>
    <List id="list" items="{/Orders}">
     <StandardListItem title="{CustomerID}" info="{ShipAddress}"/>
    </List>
   </Panel>
  </mvc:View> 
        </script>


  <script>
   // define a new (simple) Controller type
   sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {
    
    onInit: function(){
     var oFiltersModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
     sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oFiltersModel, "filtersModel");
    },
    
    _calculateFilters: function(){     
     var oSelect = this.getView().byId("comboBox"),
      oListBinding = this.getView().byId("list").getBinding("items"),
      oFiltersModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("filtersModel"),
      oCustomerFilterValue = oFiltersModel.getProperty("/customerFilter"),
      oShipAddressValue = oFiltersModel.getProperty("/shipAddressFilter"),
      oFilters = [];
     
     if(oCustomerFilterValue){
      oFilters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("CustomerID", "EQ", oCustomerFilterValue));
     }
     if(oShipAddressValue){
      oFilters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("ShipAddress", "Contains", oShipAddressValue));
     }
     
     oListBinding.filter(oFilters);
    }
   });
 
 
 
   /*** THIS IS THE "APPLICATION" CODE ***/

   // create some dummy JSON data
   var data = {
    actionName: "Say Hello"
   };

   // instantiate the View
   var myView = sap.ui.xmlview({viewContent:jQuery('#view1').html()}); // accessing the HTML inside the script tag above

   // create a Model and assign it to the View
   var uri = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc"; // local proxy for cross-domain access
   var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(uri, {
    maxDataServiceVersion: "2.0"
   }); 
   myView.setModel(oModel);
         

   // put the View onto the screen
   myView.placeAt('content');

  </script>
 
 </head>
 <body id='content' class='sapUiBody'>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. but this way the filters will stack every time you change the filters or perform a new search. any thoughts on how to solve that?

Comment: Give and ID to the Filter objects, so you can identify them in the array of current filters.
Then whenever you add a new filter, check if there is another one with the same ID as the new one. If so, pop it and push your new one.

Comment: on this link:https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Filter.html i see no parameters to give the filter an id. so how can i do that?

Comment: Sorry @freshrebel you are right... I didn't realize that sap.ui.core.Filter inherits directly from sap.ui.base.Object, and 'id' property is introduced by sap.ui.base.ManagedObject...

In this case I don't know how it can be done without gathering all the filter data again from all your filtering controls and rebuild the whole filters array each time.

Maybe a good idea is to create a "filters" model in the view, bind your filtering controls values with this model and whenever you need to filter your table, get the values from the model and build all the Filters again.

Comment: ok but my filters(so not the searchfiel) are comming from a dialog like this: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ViewSettingsDialog/preview . can i get the values from the dialog even after it is closed?

Comment: What you can do is to set a model in the Component scope. This model can be accessed from any View/Dialog whithin your app. So you can bind the filter values from the Dialog as well as from any of your views.
To define this model you should create it as `var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel()` and then set it in the Component scope with `sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "filtersModel")`. Whenever you want to access them to get/set a property just get core again: `sap.ui.getCore().getModel("filtersModel")`

Comment: I have edited the suggested soution with this new approach